# How to get values of selected radiobutton in a recyclerview?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-recyclerview, radio-group, cardview

Dynamically, i have added multiple options under one question in recycleview. Now a user can select one option inside each questions.Look at the below image,
[image]

`Recyclerview Adapter` class is,

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder,int position) {
        final PollQstWithAns poll = dataList.get(position);

        holder.txt_poll_question.setText(poll.getPollQstName());

        for (int i = 0; i < poll.getOptionList().size(); i++) {
            final PollsData mPollsOptionsList = poll.getOptionList().get(i);

            final RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(context);
            rb.setText(mPollsOptionsList.getAns1());
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

                ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
                        new int[][]{

                                new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled},
                                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled}
                        },
                        new int[]{

                                Color.DKGRAY
                                , ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary)

                        }
                );
                rb.setButtonTintList(colorStateList);
                rb.invalidate();
                rb.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.gray));
            }

            holder.optionRadioGroup.addView(rb);

        }
    }
```

I want to get all checked values from each questions, if user select the `RadioButton` inside the `RadioGroup`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on when you want to use the information there are 2 ways of doing that.

If you want to wait for the user to check all the questions and then get the values(e.g. Send Answers button,or something similar) you can use getCheckedRadioButtonId() from the RadioGroup object.

If you want to use the info right away (as user selects it) you can add a listener on the radio group object: setOnCheckedChangeListener() on the radio group object.

Comment: Hey. I can give you an answer with code tonight if you don't get it working by then. I'll edit my post

Comment: I not able to getting options under each questions(name and id). could you please elaborate me with code? thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: This is not a valid answer, it's just an alghoritm